# Why does an odd number plus one, not necessarily entail it being even?

Tags: arithmetic, definition

Why does an odd number plus one, not necessarily entail it being even?

For example, $\sqrt{5} + 1$ is not even.

Comment: $\sqrt{5}$ is not considered an odd number.  Odd numbers are integers.  Thus $\sqrt{5}$ is neither odd nor even.

Comment: Actually the question of $\sqrt5+1$ being odd or even makes sense in the ring $R=\Bbb{Z}[\phi]$, where $\phi$ is the Golden ratio, and even/odd is defined by determining whether an element belongs to the unique ideal of index two in $R$. As $(1+\sqrt5)/2\in R$, in this sense $1+\sqrt5$ **IS** even.

Answer (score 3):

An odd number is one of the form $2n+1$ where $n$ is an integer. If $m$ is odd, then $m +1 = 2n+1 +1 = 2(n+1)$ for some integer $n$, and so $m+1$ is even.

As indicated in the comment, $\sqrt{5}$ is not an integer, so the designation of odd/even does not apply.

Comment: But here is the "odd" thing. Suppose sqrt(5) = a/b, then a^2/b^2 is equal to five, which is clearly odd. Therefore, a/b must be odd, therefore the square root of five must also be odd.  Which cannot be the case.

Comment: I'll grant that 5 is odd. However, $\frac{10}{2}=5$ yet 10 and 2 are both even. Don't forget that you state nothing about a and b which could share a common factor that could cancel out.

Comment: @MichaelLee We only have $a/b$ is odd implies $a^2/b^2$ is odd, but $a^2/b^2$ is odd does not necessary conclude that $a/b$ is odd. $a/b$ must not be even, but may be an integer at all (like the case of $\sqrt{5}$).